# Origin server not finding current representation for target resource when using GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, java, tomcat, extensions

I installed Java 8, Tomcat 8.5.12 and GeoServer 2.11.2. When I navigate to localhost:8080/geoserver it is giving me this weird 404 error:

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

The Tomcat logs show:

```
SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/geoserver] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Why is the GeoServer (`/geoserver`) servlet failing to start or where else I can look to determine why?

Comment: Can you show more of the tomcat log esp. the lines before the severe error occured? Maybe it gives some hint about what happened.

Comment: For me, this was first, an old CATALINA_OPTS flag for the JVM, and next a broken GeoServer extension, and finally a missing GeoServer extensions that another was dependent on. In all three cases, I was getting that same error message because GeoServer was failing to deploy.